Understanding ARMA model fit
I fit an ARMA(1,1) model using statsmodels in python to a univariate data series and got seemingly very significant fit.

Log likelihood: 200,000


AIC/BIC/HQIC: -400,000


AR.L1 : 0.1 (z 45)


MA.L1: -0.09 (z -45)


sigma2: z: 200

But I get a warning saying cov matrix is near singular with condition number 2e16

Do almost equal and opposite AR and MA coefficients point to an issue?
Which covariance matrix is it referring to?
How do I interpret these results overall- especially super high AIC/BIC etc.
High z score for sigma2- is it simply saying residuals are significantly not-normal. Does it matter with high AIC?


those fit measures depend on the data, so absolute values are difficult to evaluate. You could estimate a pure MA(!) and an AR(1) and check whether they almost fit as well, e.g loglike, aic, ... values almost the same.

What does AR.L1 : 0.1 (z 45) mean? What is 0.1 and what is 45? Why do you think AIC/BIC are super high? Depending on the data, they could be many times higher. What is the z-score for sigma2? Is it some sort of test statistic? Why should sigma2 (which I presume is the error variance) tell you anything about the normality of the residuals?
